# Converting some columns from pandas dataframe to list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `dataframe`. I would like some of the data to be converted to a list of list. The columns I'm interested in are the `index`, `Name`, and `Births`. My code works, but it seems inefficient and for some reason the letter L is added to the end of each index.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['Bob', 968, 'Male'], ['Jessica', 341, 'Female'], ['Mary', 77, 'Female'], ['John', 578, 'Male'], ['Mel', 434, 'Female']]
headers = ['Names', 'Births', 'Gender']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=headers)
indexes = df.index.values.tolist()
mylist =  [[x] for x in indexes]

for x in mylist:
    x.extend([df.ix[x[0],'Names'], df.ix[x[0],'Births']])

print mylist
```

Desired Output:

```
[[0, 'Bob', 968], [1, 'Jessica', 341], [2, 'Mary', 77], [3, 'John', 578], [4, 'Mel', 434]]
```

Comment: I just ran your code as is using python 2.7.9 and pandas 0.16.2 and the output was exactly what you want.

Comment: @JulienGrenier. Yes I am looking for efficiency improvements to my code. Also the tolist() functionality seems to add an L to the end of things so the actual ouput is: `[[0L, 'Bob', 968], [1L, 'Jessica', 341], [2L, 'Mary', 77], [3L, 'John', 578], [4L, 'Mel', 434]]`

Comment: I would also love to see a solution to this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use `.values.tolist()` as you mentioned?

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# =================================================
data = [['Bob', 968, 'Male'], ['Jessica', 341, 'Female'], ['Mary', 77, 'Female'], ['John', 578, 'Male'], ['Mel', 434, 'Female']]
headers = ['Names', 'Births', 'Gender']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=headers)

# nested list
# ============================
df.reset_index()[['index', 'Names', 'Births']].values.tolist()

Out[46]: 
[[0, 'Bob', 968],
 [1, 'Jessica', 341],
 [2, 'Mary', 77],
 [3, 'John', 578],
 [4, 'Mel', 434]]
```

Comment: This outputs: `[[0L, 'Bob', 968L], [1L, 'Jessica', 341L], [2L, 'Mary', 77L], [3L, 'John', 578L], [4L, 'Mel', 434L]]`. Why are the L's being added?

Comment: @user2242044 L means 'Long' integer. I didn't see that 'L' appended to my output. Let me think about possible causes.

Comment: Also is there is an opposite function of `drop()` such as include? For example say my dataframe had 40 columns and I wanted two of them.

Comment: @user2242044: First of all, I don't see the L in my shell. Also the L only means that those are longs instead of integers.

Comment: @user2242044 instead using `drop()`, you can select just those columns you want. I've modified the code.

Comment: @user2242044 can you try this `df.reset_index()[['index', 'Names', 'Births']].values.astype(str).tolist()`? Does it still produce something with `L` appended?

Comment: When I type in `print(type(df))`, this shows `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this works (based on Jianxun Li's answer and comments):

```
import pandas as pd

# Data
data = [['Bob', 968, 'Male'], ['Jessica', 341, 'Female'], ['Mary', 77, 'Female'], ['John', 578, 'Male'], ['Mel', 434, 'Female']]
headers = ['Names', 'Births', 'Gender']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=headers)

# Output
print df.reset_index()[['index', 'Names', 'Births']].values.astype(str).tolist()
```

Thank you Jianxun Li, this also helped me :-)

In general, one can use the following to **transform the complete dataframe into a list of lists** (which is what I needed):

```
df.values.astype(str).tolist()
```